# Switch not updating its value in UI

Tags: android, switch-statement

I want to set a UI, which will call values from the database, and then put this values in the switch widget. i dont know what's wrong here. so here's the code.

activity:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity{
    //declaration of switches
    private Switch switch01;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_akla_box_workflow_open);
       new GetMyActivityTask(myActivity.this, serverUrl, email,password).execute(0);

       switch01 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.Switch01);
    }

    public void onDisplayAfterTask(Object result){
       //result.istrue only returns true/false value
       switch01.setActivate(result.isTrue());
    }

}
```

I add `Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(switch01.isActivate()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` to check if my switch has the right value, and it is, but still the switch in my android is false, how come the switch does not display the value same  as displayed in my toast.maketext..

Im sorry hoped this is not a long post. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is `GetMyActivityTask`? In other words what does it extend? Also is `onDisplayAfterTask` called from and where do you make your `Toast` message?

Comment: i now know the answer to my problem, i should have used `switch.setActivated(true)`, instead i should use `switch.setChecked()`

Comment: thaanks @Squonk for a very quick reply.
i found the answer to my problem, :)

getactivitytask is just an asynctask which return some values, and in postExecute it calls the method above `onDisplayAfterTask`,,

Comment: @Karl good for you to find the solution by yourself :) Why don't you try to write it as the answer? In addition, Android usually use "checked" as the indicator for `CompoundButton` (including `Switch`, `ToggleButton`, `CheckBox`, `RadioButton`), whereas "activated" is just one of the general `View` state.

Comment: @Squonk yeah i tried to but it says i can only answer my own questoin after 8hours or have a points 150+,

oh i see now the difference between checked and activated, i am quite new in this matters, thank you very much :D hope to see you in future posts :D